# Visual Studio 2015 C++ Compile Time Freezes computer until compilation completes

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Windows 10 x64
Visual Studio 2015 Community

I have tried reformatting my PC, reinstalling, but it doesn't work.
Basically, every time the C++ is on "Generating Code" it will freeze my computer until it completes compilling. If the code is small, it will freeze but for w/e amount it takes to compile. The freeze won't let me use my computer at all, it will freeze even my screen and any video game I'm running.

i5 3570k
12 GB Corsair 1600 Mhz
500 GB HDD 7200 RPM

What can I do?

Comment: Can you open Task Manager or Process Explorer before compilation running. Is CPU too high?

Comment: Describe how you're "compiling" please. Are you simply doing a build + run?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Just a Release x64 Build, default VS2015 project settings. CPU usage is ~5%, I can't see my CPU usage when It's generating code as it would just freeze entirely until it completes.

Comment: As you list the brand and speed of your memory this sounds like a home built system.  Verify that you have all the right drivers installed for your hardware.  Compiling is disk intensive, and if don't have the right driver for your chipset (to allow windows to do disk access efficiently) everything will run slow.

Comment: <sarcasm> Potentially you should run simpler builds. What were you thinking when using all CPUs? That the OS is intelligent enough to manage this simple rule? </sarcasm>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its difficult to say without seeing at least system information (.nfo) file. However there are some things that worth checking:

1. See if you have `/MP` option enabled (`Project
   options->C/C++->All options->Multi-processor compilation`). Try to
   explicitly disable it;
2. System freezes could also happen because of the hard drive poor state. Check it using any HDD verification utility, see if your computer freezes on HDD-intensive operations like bulk file copying.

Comment: Tried disabling /MP, did a rebuild, and it won't freeze my computer! But why does /MP does freeze it so horrendous?! (100% cpu usage - if no fix is given, I will select this answer as the solution)

Comment: If `/MP` flag is enabled, Visual Studio creates one compiler instance for each *effective* processor in the system. You could limit processor count using optional number after the flag, eg. `/MP2`

Comment: What is the use of a multi-processor machine then? What do you do on a single CPU machine?

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio 2015 you can go to Tools->Settings, search for `VC++ Project Settings` and tweak `Maximum Concurrent C++ compilations`. The default is 0, which means "use all processors"

Comment: What is the use of a multi-CPU machine?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Why would you have a n-CPU machine, if you would always have to save at least one CPU for foreground processes? This is the task of an OS to control priority of the processes. What about a single CPU machine?

Comment: The fact that my PC gets painstrakingly slow when VS uses all of my 4 cores for compilation is reason enough for me. Apparently it prioritizes visual studio too high.

Answer (score 0):

The comment on the other answer confirms it's a CPU problem, not IO. Still the solutions for both cases would be the same. Decrease the process priority of Visual Studio. You can easily do this in Task Manager. This will lower both CPU and IO priority, so everything else will now have a relatively higher priority.

You will still hit 100% CPU load, though. That is to say, the foreground gets everything it needs, and the compiler gets the leftover CPU time. No point in idling a CPU when there's work to be done. (It may be slightly lower when the compiler is waiting for the HDD to read a file)

Comment: no. You do not want to decrease the priority of the IDE  but of the compiler/linker.

Comment: The compiler and linker both are ephemeral child processes of the IDE. Because they're child processes, they inherit the IDE's priority, and because they're ephemeral it's hard to set them directly.

Comment: I knew this when I added my comment. The reason that you do not want to change the priority of the IDE is, that you want to keep it responsive while the compiler/linker is running. And you want to keep it responsive while some other process with normal priority needs CPU time/